# NSException thrown on uialert

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have an ios app that throws an alert when an error code is given.

the code is this.

```
NSString *errorMessage = [[json valueForKey:@"message"] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
    if(errorMessage == nil)
        errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error Code : %@", [json valueForKey:@"code"]];
    UIAlertController *alertView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:errorMessage message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"확인" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [alertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [alertView addAction:yesButton];
    [self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
    return nil;
```

But it keeps giving me

2020-04-23 17:06:49.247744+0900 timekeeper[64197:20858252] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x19e8f496c 0x19e60d028 0x19ede05e0 0x19ebcf828 0x1a2dce250 0x1a2dcf648 0x1a2027d74 0x1a20234b8 0x1a202372c 0x1a2023a6c 0x1a2028630 0x1a2028474 0x1a2009364 0x1a23b0a1c 0x1a23b1104 0x1a23c7214 0x1a23bfd08 0x1a23c175c 0x1a23c3d0c 0x1a23c4270 0x1a23c3c58 0x1a23c3eec 0x1023b2924 0x1023b1028 0x19ebadfa4 0x19ece9a74 0x19e5fd840 0x19e6059f4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

error

what is the problem?? It worked fine few days ago.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to present the alert controller on a thread which isn't the main thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to present the `UIAlertController` in the `main` thread.

Something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Hope this helps